# convert a series of number to unique, random appearing string

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, character-encoding

I have a sequence of decimal numbers (from 0 to 36^5), the goal is to get unique (non-repeating), random appearing strings composed 5 characters (uppercase and digits).

e.g.

```
    1 get transformed to ACD1R

    2 get transformed to BD5T2
```

an essential condition is the generated strings appear to be random but underneath there's a bijective function between input and output of the transformation function.

I have tried with base64, do you have any idea what's the pythonic cryptographic way, or the solution to this problem is not feasible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using md5, and cut the hexdigest to only 5 characters

```
from hashlib import md5
for i in range(1, 10):
    target = md5(str(i).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()[0:5].upper()
    print("{number} get transformed to {target}".format(number=i, target=target)))
```

You got:

```
1 get transformed to C4CA4
2 get transformed to C81E7
3 get transformed to ECCBC
4 get transformed to A87FF
5 get transformed to E4DA3
6 get transformed to 16790
7 get transformed to 8F14E
8 get transformed to C9F0F
9 get transformed to 45C48
```

but this cannot guarantee you to be unique, you can keep a hash table to check the duplicate ones, and make another one for those conflicts.

Comment: your solution is a good one except that it lacks the unicity condition, meaning two numbers may generate the same string, i tested your solution and found a collision at iteration 1172.